# dynamicField in django-haystack SOLR config

Tags: solr, django-haystack

How to configure search_indexes.py to index dynamicFields in django-haystack. I'm using SOLR as the search engine for haystack.

Answer (score 1):

If you are using Haystack's `build_solr_schema` management command to create your schema.xml, notice that it automatically includes various dynamicFields for popular field types. For example, [check out the schema template for Haystack v2.1](https://github.com/toastdriven/django-haystack/blob/v2.1.0/haystack/templates/search_configuration/solr.xml#L137-146). (This looks like it's been there since Haystack v1.)

This allows you to create dynamically-named fields in your search index's prepare method. For example, if you were indexing notes that could have an id string for your ever-changing group of partners, you could do this:

```
def prepare(self, obj):
    self.prepared_data = super(NoteIndex, self).prepare(obj)
    for (partner_name, partner_id) in get_partners():
        self.prepared_data['%s_s' % partner_name] = partner_id
    return self.prepared_data
```

The key thing here is that the field name ends with "_s", which according to the schema is a dynamic name for string types.

Unfortunately, these dynamic partner fields are not explicitly defined at the top of your SearchIndex class. You may want to mention this in a comment.

Answer (score 0):

As far as I can see in the source code of django-haystack 1.2.* you can't do this. You can write own schema instead of generating it using management commands and use it.

Answer (score 0):

As [@nofinator](https://stackoverflow.com/users/245915/nofinator) say, you can do this in `.prepare` method of `SearchIndex` class by concatinating field name with prefix from SOLR `Schema.xml`.

By default Haystack(current ver. is 2.1.1) ships with some default DynamicField like a `*_s`. But if you want, you can make your own DynamicField.

In my project ill make `attr_*` field and its work fine.

All you need to do, is add this field, with same syntax in `Schema.xml`
You can do in manualy or overriding standart Haystack `build_solr_schema` management command.(Btw, its uses standart django render template fnc. so its pretty easy.